# Mathematica Homework Question

Tags: mathematica

I had a mathematica assignment the other day that was fairly simple. I thought I did it correctly, but I guess not.

Question: Write a single Mathematica Command which will display (plot) both $y = x\sin(2x + \pi)$ and $y = e^x$ on a single set of axes with $x$ in the interval $-7 \le x \le 5$

I had put:

`Plot[{xsin[2x + Pi], e^x}, {-7, x, 5}]`

Could anyone explain what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You need Sin[x] and Exp[x]. Then {x,-7,5}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space between `x Sin`. Capitalize `Sin` (its a function) and the range for variable `x` is given as `{variable NAME, lower BOUND, upper BOUND}`

Plot[{x Sin[2 x + Pi], E^x}, {x, -7, 5}]

*edit* and you need 'E'  to get the constant *e* in Mathematica.